# Is it bad form to declare all queues and exchanges on every channel?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging

I'm starting out with RabbitMQ and I have an architectural dilemma. I was about to build message consumer classes which declare the queues and exchanges they consume from and write to. In order to avoid mismatches in queue configuration options and names between multiple consumers and producers, I created a "repository" class which holds the queue names and options.

And then it struck me... Instead of having each consumer class contain the list of the queues it uses, why not have a global `configChannel(Channel)` static method which would declare **ALL** queues and exchanges for every channel I create? This way, I wouldn't have to worry about the order in which they're declared. Is there a downside? If not, why isn't this kind of approach recommended in the documentation (as far as I could see)?

#### edit

I found some more info here:

http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-June/027880.html

> I think the expectation is that producers and consumers should declare the things that they directly interact with."

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-discuss/Jp49IRe693o

> Typically, both the producers and consumers will declare the exchanges
> of interest.  But only consumers will declare and bind the queues,
> because they know which messages they wish to receive.

If I understand correctly, to avoid messages getting black-holed (queue not declared yet) when the producer only declares the exchange it publishes to, some synchronization is necessary to make sure the consumer(s) is(are) started first and declares its(their) queue. Why bother with the potential trouble and not declare queues up front for every producer and consumer? I imagine there are applications which require dynamically created queues so that's another story. My argument pertains to the *static* or permanent application message queues when they exist.

Comment: I would guess that it depends on how many queues are you are talking about.

Comment: For now, about 15 queues among which 3 are persistent.

Comment: queues cannot be persistent, messages are persistent, queues can be durable and they can be autodelete.  I am a bit unclear on what you are trying to achieve here, but there should be no problem creating the queues ahead of time.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed-up the terminology. I meant to write 3 *durable* queues (which will contain persistent messages). I'm essentially asking: why not create the whole network of queues and exchanges for each channel at a single place instead of risking inconsistencies by declaring them piecewise?

Comment: What I do not understand is where the inconsistencies come from.  The process of connecting to queue is the same as declaring one.  So why create it ahead of time

Comment: What I meant was inconsistencies between queue declarations (the settings like durable, etc.) in the consumer and producer. Obviously, as I've just realized, this can't happen if only the consumers declare the queues... The trick is then to make sure the consumers are all created and their queues declared before producers start publishing messages. One solution to this is to have both producer and consumer declare *all* queues. I guess there are other solutions which I'll search for right now.

Comment: having the producer declare queues is possible to make sure that you do not miss messages, make sure they are set to autodelete=false as I think that is what you need more that durable.  But as you say you cannot have inconsistencies otherwise it wont work anyway.  Declaring the queues in advance will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be easier to declare queues, exchanges and bindings as an administrative step via a script.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I was thinking of having a central deployment script as well.